# O que está ocorrendo no meu programa em C?

Tags: c, array, matriz

Tenho somente que somar as linhas porém os valores não fazem sentido:

[image: A soma da primeira linha deu 19 e nem se fala da segunda]

Aqui o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){

    int matriz[6][6],i,h,somalinha[6];

    for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
        for(h=0;h<=4;h++){
            printf("Digite os valores de uma matriz 3x3:\n");
            scanf("%d",&matriz[i][h]);
            somalinha[i] = somalinha[i]+matriz[i][h];
        }
        printf("O resultado da soma da linha %d eh %d\n",i,somalinha[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas. Eu dei uma organizada e resolvi os problemas. O `include` não faz sentido, o *array* não está zero na declaração, então a soma não ocorre corretamente e a declaração está sendo maior do que deveria, basta, se é 3X3 declare apenas isto, também dei uma modernizada:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int matriz[3][3], somalinha[3] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int h = 0; h < 3; h++) {
            printf("Digite os valores de uma matriz 3x3:\n");
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][h]);
            somalinha[i] += matriz[i][h];
        }
        printf("O resultado da soma da linha %d eh %d\n", i, somalinha[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gnAatY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tbpfunpo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/MatrixFill.c).

Comment: Obrigado, eu tinha esquecido de iniciar o vetor com 0 mesmo

Answer (score 9):

Você esqueceu de inicializar o vetor `somalinha` com valores iguais a zero. O programa está pegando lixo de memória.

Outro detalhe é que você declara uma matriz 6x6, mas usa uma matriz 5x5 no laço de repetição.

Comment: sim, é que meu professor disse que quando se trata de matrizes é sempre bom deixar um espaço maior

Comment: Acho que isso só se aplica a vetores do tipo char, que precisam de um caractere a mais para armazenar o caractere nulo (que indica o fim da string).

Comment: ah então se é assim, obrigado kk não sabia